# VBA Excel - Insert a partial row in active cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have been experimenting with VBA code and wanted to figure out how to insert a partial row where there is an active cell (Range from B:E).

A beginner here, will appreciate the input

Thanks!

```
Sub Adding()
'
' Adding Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+g
'
    Range("B177:E177").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-162
    Range("K9").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K9:K1936"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("K9:K1936").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1904
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1902
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1893
    Range("L177").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "Test. "
End Sub
```

Comment: so you want to insert 4 cells (shifting the current ones down) from columns B:E in the row of the activecell? (also please keep questions to 1 actual question. you have two here

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Yes, that is correct. I also removed the second question sorry about that.

Comment: @Jeeped I have made the adjustment, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are staring out, you might want to read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Also, the only VBA that is required to insert a few cells is

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B177:E177").Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

...the rest of the code is just fluff & tinkering and doesn't have to do with the question.  Recording Macros is a great way to quickly get pointed in the right direction and getting exposed to new properties/functions; but once you get what you need, remove the extra fluff (anything that says `.Select/Selection/ActiveWindow`) which just slows the code down anyway.

---

There is a difference between `Activecell` and `Selection`.

- ***Selection*** is a Range variable of all the cells that are selected/highlighted.
- ***ActiveCell*** is a Range that contains only 1 cell.  The cell that is highlighted white and if you start typing the value will change.  You can change the active cell to the *{previous}*/next cell in a selection by hitting the *{shift+}* ***Tab*** key.

So to insert the cells that are selected, use:

```
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

for just the active cell, use:

```
ActiveCell.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

*Note: **Selection/ActiveCell** are always based on the `ActiveworkBook.Activeworksheet`.*

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have made that change, but it looks like it didn't make the proper action that I wanted. I was looking to have this done based on the active cell, so whichever cell I have currently clicked.